# Mysql order by and group by query

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I have an SQL table and I made an SQL query which orders by latest update and groups by `fleetID` afterwards.

The table is in this image:

[image: table]

The query should return **lines 3 and 5** but mine returns **1 and 3**.
My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * from test order by lastupdate )l group by l.fleetid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a valid SQL statement -- even if your version of MySQL happens to accept it.

If you want the last update date for each fleet, then you want to *filter* the data, not *aggregate* it.  That calls for `where`, not `group by`:

```
select t.*
from test t
where t.lastupdate = (select max(t2.lastupdate)
                      from test t2
                      where t2.fleetid = t.fleetid
                     );
```